Move a texture towards the center of UV (vortex) on a flat surface without scaling
So basically I'm trying to make a flat portal/vortex wich looks like the typical hyperspace loop with only a texture.
Here is the texture and the effect I'm looking for:

I was thinking about stretching the image along the Z axis of the UV center but I dont really know how

maybe simply create a cylinder and stretch a noise along its length?

@moonboots I wanted to know if its possible to do such thing with only shader nodes because I know you can modify the mesh to be the actual wormhole and just slide the texture or play with the UVs to get the same effect.
